# Java Native Interface callback jstrings as a jobjectArray Signature error of jmethodID

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I become an error if I try to pass jstrings to Java in a jobjectArray from the JNI. I researched this many times and it should work. But my Signature [Ljava/lang/String does not work. When I pass nothing it works. When I return the jobjectArray it also works. When I try to send the array to the Java-method then occurs an error. So I think the Sinature does not work. I hope somebody can help me so it would be also easier for others. I will send my little program to demonstrate my error.

Here is the C-code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "clas.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_clas_function(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jobjectArray in_array){
    jclass icls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, jobj);
    jmethodID jmid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, icls, "callback", "([Ljava/lang/String)V");
    if(jmid == 0){
        printf("False Signature\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, jobj, jmid, in_array);
}
```

And the Java-code:

```
public class clas {

    public clas(){
        String[] c = {"something", "something else", "another one"};
        function(c);
    }

    public native void function(String[] in_strg);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        clas c = new clas();
    }
    private void callback(String[] in_string){
        System.out.println("reached");
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("clas");
    }

}
```

Thank you ;).

Comment: Don't write your own method signatures. Use the output of `javap -s`. It is never wrong.

Comment: Thank you EJP! Can you give me an example please? ;D I would like it...

Comment: `javap -s clas | grep -A 2 "void callback(java\.lang\.String\[\])"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of a String object is `Ljava/lang/String;`, not `Ljava/lang/String`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It just works ;) Oh men I thought I must set the semicolon if I would add another argument. :D